# How to create simple PHP COMET server page displaying current time?

Tags: php, time, comet

How to create simple PHP COMET server page displaying current time? I need code implementation (because it should be trivial) - not theory or just links to library sites. Simple text line conteining corrent time and updating each second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll recommend reading [here](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start) the section "Comet with classic AJAX".
It contains a succinct `PHP` implementation, and a `Javascript` client side code using `prototype.js`.